# AutoCompleteTextView 1. add buttons, 2. create contact adapter, 3. spaces in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, contacts, autocompletetextview

i am trying to make a Compose New Message screen like the Messaging app built-in in Android 4.1

1. i noticed that when a person selects a contact, there is a Button sort of thing in the AutoCompleteTextView inserted. HOW is that possible? Please help, as I do not even have any idea to give a starting code for it.
   P.S. : I would LOVE to implement something like in the "Tags" entry in StackOverflow when creating a new post. I.E. the words (matched contacts) being replaced by buttons, with a little X on the right edge to remove them! :-)
2. how do you create the adapter which loads so fast? one idea would be to cache a List of all contacts (names, phone no.s, phone no. types). any other ideas ?
   (like, if we could query the content provider with an initial search string of say 2 characters, which would reduce the no. of autocomplete results tremenduously, thus reducing the time taken to load the adapter. but of course, this would require to set the adapter for the autocompletetextview as each character is typed. My doubt is that, can the ContactsContract be queried for search results starting with a few given letters, rather than just scanning the entire database from the starting using a Cursor?)
3. the autocompletetextview does not recognize spaces, and just gives no results.
   i have already read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/OrsN2xRpDmA)  but could not implement it, does anyone have any working code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You free to look at source code of built-in messaging app at Android [GitHub](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms). All you need is patience to read and understand code. And i remind you that **not all of code are in public SDK** so careful in usage.

1, The MultiAutoComplete with Contact tag [RecipientEditTextView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java). And [RecipientsEditor](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/RecipientsEditor.java) is class extended `RecipientEditTextView` they use it in app
Update : Here is [layout](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/res/layout/compose_message_activity.xml#L37) of Compose screen. Line 37 is the autocompletetextview you want. And below is its layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<com.android.mms.ui.RecipientsEditor
    android:id="@+id/recipients_editor"
    android:hint="@string/to_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
/>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/recipients_picker"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_contacts"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

Comment: one would honestly need days and days to figure things out for such little things. I had taken a look into it before too. but what i kind of need right now is code for exactly the autocompletetextview and the adapter that it uses, and the onclick actions. can maybe you/anyone please help me out with that?

Comment: SO is not code provided site so in order to get running code is hard. You must figure it out yourself. I only had custom android2.2 messaging app. I will add new feature in 4.0 contact tag in autocompletetextview in 1 or 2 week. So i'll edit my post. Just my advice, you want it so you must work.

Comment: ok thanks for the RecipientEditTextView and RecipientsEditor links!

now i have a doubt, if i replace the AutoCompleteTextView with that, then do i have to add any extra lines in the xml of the view, as in to import the class from my package or something?

Answer (score 0):

I built [TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) to solve this issue as there did not appear to be a simple way to do this. Here's a basic example solving points 1 and 3:

```
public class ContactsCompletionView extends TokenCompleteTextView {
    public ContactsCompletionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getViewForObject(Object object) {
        Person p = (Person)object;

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)l.inflate(R.layout.contact_token, (ViewGroup)ContactsCompletionView.this.getParent(), false);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getName());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object defaultObject(String completionText) {
        //Stupid simple example of guessing if we have an email or not
        int index = completionText.indexOf('@');
        if (index == -1) {
            return new Person(completionText, completionText.replace(" ", "") + "@example.com");
        } else {
            return new Person(completionText.substring(0, index), completionText);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout code for contact_token (you'll need to find your own x drawable)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/token_background">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Test Me"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/x"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Token backgound drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ffafafaf" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Person object code

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Person(String n, String e) { name = n; email = e; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return name; }
}
```

Sample activity

```
public class TokenActivity extends Activity {
    ContactsCompletionView completionView;
    Person[] people;
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        people = new Person[]{
                new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"),
                new Person("Margaret Smith", "margaret@example.com"),
                new Person("Max Jordan", "max@example.com"),
                new Person("Meg Peterson", "meg@example.com"),
                new Person("Amanda Johnson", "amanda@example.com"),
                new Person("Terry Anderson", "terry@example.com")
        };

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people);

        completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
        completionView.setTokenClickStyle(TokenCompleteTextView.TokenClickStyle.Delete);
    }
}
```

Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I tried the library but am getting no classdeffound error. This library looks very promising but am unable to even compile it. I am using ecllipse and tried both importing project and adding the jar.